# Can I capture a label not found in the test string using regex?

Tags: regex

Assuming I have some strings of the following type:

```
session opened by (uid=0)
session opened by scotty
```

Is it possible to write a regex that will either capture the text "`root`" if `(uid=0)` is found in the string, otherwise capture the normal user name (i.e. `scotty`)?

Comment: what language are you using?

Comment: If you're asking what regex engine, I'm not entirely sure. I'm open to trying any solution, see if it works.

Comment: not engine, language (c/java/js), where (or in what language) are you trying to implement this?

Comment: I am not trying to implement this in any language. I am using a software program that uses regex.

Answer (score 0):

Regex does not allow you to capture anything that *is missing* from the input string. If you know the structure of the input text, you can have a regex pattern return the required part. Here is an example that works for .NET-based regex flavor:

```
(?s)(?<=\(uid=0\).*opened by )\w+

Matches Found:
[0][0] = scotty
```